# Can we integrate forms on wordpress using CiviCRM?

Tags: wordpress, forms

I just wanted to ask what plugins or any ways to integrate forms in wordpress that can integrate using CiviCRM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Contact form 7 and CiviCRM [extension](https://github.com/CiviCooP/be.werkmetzin.wpcivi) to integrate forms in wordpress. It enables sending data from a Contact Form to CiviCRM if you enter the data in the Contact Form in the correct way.

More details of using this can be found [here](https://github.com/CiviCooP/be.werkmetzin.wpcivi/blob/master/README.md).

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: The extension Pradeep had mentioned is the CiviCRM endpoint and is build custom for one specific client.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using [Caldera Forms CiviCRM](https://github.com/mecachisenros/caldera-forms-civicrm) which has great integration with WordPress via the superb Caldera Forms plugin. Check out [the tutorial by Tadpole Collective](https://tadpole.cc/using-caldera-form-processors-to-collect-civicrm-contact-data/) to get yourself going with Caldera Forms CiviCRM.

Comment: I also recommend the Caldera Forms integration. @user2520909

Comment: Also - I assume profiles don't work for you either?

Answer (score 0):

As pradeep mentioned there is the [Contact Form 7 wordpress plugin](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-civicrm-integration/) this plugin sends the form submission to a CiviCRM API. You can use the [Form Processor extension](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/form-procesor) to create and API end point to handle the form submission.

[I have written a blog post](https://civicrm.org/blog/jaapjansma/usings-civicrm-form-processor-extension-to-handle-form-submissions-from-an-external) on how to handle form submissions with the form processor and will include a word press example.

Below a screenshot of the Wordpress contact form configuration.

[image: Wordpress contact form configuration]